# Two codes which one more correct?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have two codes to traverse a list and output the data on the list.

Now I think the first is the correct one, as I think the second will cause an exception to happen, am I correct?

Question answered.

Comment: Both could potentially throw NPE

Comment: What is the code for `LinkedNode`?

Comment: *I think the second will cause an exception to happen*: try it, and you'll see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second version *could* throw an NPE.  (Consider the case where `list` is `null`.)

But a more important problem is that the second version *will not* output the last element of the list.  Ever.

You should be able to verify this by "hand-executing" the code, with a pencil and paper.  I recommend that you do this, because it will help you understand what is actually going on.

(Alternatively, you could compile and run the two versions with some example lists, though this will give you less insight.)

Comment: Yeah I did the hand counting version.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is probably the one you want.  You should also make sure that the `data` field isn't null.

One potential issue with the second one is that if `list` is null in the first place, then trying to get `current.next` in the while loop condition will throw null pointer exception.